# Show a lot of Data in a chart (Create Waveform)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, performance

I want to create a SoundEditor with a wave form.

I want to show all samples in this wave form but samples count > 9000000 thus my program works very poorly.

please help me, for create a waveform that show all samples rapidly.

i use from MSChart for Framework 3.5 sp1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to approach this from the other side: you have an upper limit for the amount of detail determined by the user+screen.

So think in terms of: What data do I have (let's say 10.000.000) and what can I show (1000 pixels wide). You then you have to simplify 1:1000. Better determine a formula for that, don't leave it to rounding by a graphics engine.

When you add a Zoom option the ratio changes.

Comment: Of course, zoom also causes clipping, which also reduces the number of samples that have to be plotted at once.

Comment: i used from a chart so i am not limit for display width.
it is mean that i can show all sample but my problem is here that if i dont show all sample user cant edit wave with details, now if i can show all sample my program work bad. 
i want to user zoom to waveform and see samples.

Comment: @Majid: I think you want to show the whole length. But not all samples (all the time). You need a (downsample) filter.

Comment: Henk is correct.  Create a visual filter while still retaining the full data in the background (so the user can edit with details).  Handle zooming, panning, etc to re-filter.

Comment: So you usea third party control not optimized for that amount of data and wonder about bad performance? ;) Gratulations. Made my day. Your amount of data cals for a specialised solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow one pixel per sample along the time axis then you re going to need a display with 9x10^6 pixels on one of its dimensions.  Failing that, you have either to downsample to within the capabilities of your display, or implement a sliding window so that you can look at part of the waveform.

If your program is performing poorly that might be an indication that downsampling is the way to go.

Comment: And in Audio jargon, downsampling would be a low-pass filter.

Comment: i used from a chart so i am not limit for display width.

Comment: it is mean that i can show all sample but my problem is here that if i dont show all sample user cant edit wave with details, now if i can show all sample my program work bad.

Comment: i want to user zoom to waveform and see samples.